# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path - Laravel to Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, laravel, gson, retrofit2

I've built a simple API using Laravel and it is working fine. 
My Android app should consume data from this API, but for some JSON response I'm getting an error

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Before getting this error, the error was the one below:

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path

Then I `setLenient(true)` to solve it.

I've seen in many other posts that the problem is a malformed JSON, but it appears to be all good.

**JSON response that gives me error:**

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImRhMWUxNzU4YmI1YTFjMjAzZDI1MDk5OTM4YTljMjgwNDUyMjYzMDFhNjZiZmViZmJlMTQyY2FmNGU4OGUwMzc2NTZkN2RmZjI4NDUxMTEzIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZGExZTE3NThiYjVhMWMyMDNkMjUwOTk5MzhhOWMyODA0NTIyNjMwMWE2NmJmZWJmYmUxNDJjYWY0ZTg4ZTAzNzY1NmQ3ZGZmMjg0NTExMTMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTE3OTIzMzAsIm5iZiI6MTU1MTc5MjMzMCwiZXhwIjoxNTgzNDE0NzMwLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.bi4l9mpUDLoYMLWwd1JyCAfoN2GtwpnpEmGnzsoDoIP_rcTWfT9IsixX4iwtbjSdOTBFkqSD9oGz8KncI24spgnKhofZelClSP6tNtI6P8q2b_PmnefytmNfu_fWBAvSTD2Tia8-cMCu_eF9QfNoOv_9JCYAaY__DY2W_zI3u8uLv25EZQPgBiW7MIT_gm9ZnD6JJlCL4rkgUuhdDG8lkjHCryAYVBqXsGLizl6YdgBp8zMYzONzjxT4nhTARL_aywE9ejZCt5Mkh5qvoGms4zkMMAW0OIYVP_puB7MSPJAriCR1kaBO06MSNGcfAdorn5VDpfwFV8t25mftOeaM1x8IvWT1K0_Hi0BtdV2twtJ-_uHcmIn8QiF3Tc6On7YWWWGEfJw0vAGqK5RaYtWVSo5iWbAiD5rsmCQRQDsg4GnEH9AnYHjcjortBe01YuimQ4TMSIgWLpRfExwcPgQkonklWqODcE8nvuWzyKUirmm56gGj1wBZciqrYsDRTImP4Ntv1Q5Tb3r2PoFlqxfn3_qux1OQpTyzHGEOEaE9ZQnNoELjwGd5nUuFOYCOdwafIUsG0atHtoPBj_S6jTsJJdIWqQzCexchpkwBUgP5i6o1QCai7BcOnTXKJ3V6kV17SGtiP7gqTM9fvESD0BIuK4Xd0dsA8mc67_HwLJyhpXM",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_at": "2019-03-19"
}
```

**Working JSON Response:**

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "username": [
            "The username has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tested JSON with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and it says it's all good with JSON

**Not Working - Laravel JSON Response**

```
return response()->json([
       'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateString()
        ], 200);
```

**Working - Laravel JSON Response**

```
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Cadastro realizado.',
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ], 201);
```

**Android - Signin**

```
btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + etSigninUser.getText().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + etSigninPassword.getText().toString());
            Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.userLogin(
                    etSigninUser.getText().toString(),
                    etSigninPassword.getText().toString(),
                    false
            );

            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString() + " " + t.getCause());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Android - LoginResponse Model**

```
    public class LoginResponse {

    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("expires_at")
    @Expose
    private String expiresAt;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getExpiresAt() {
        return expiresAt;
    }

    public void setExpiresAt(String expiresAt) {
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
    }
}
```

**Android - Retrofit 2 Call **

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("auth/login")
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("remember_me") boolean remember_me
);
```

I can't see what is wrong with my code, everything appears to be good, why am I getting this error?
Is JSON malformed?

**EDIT 1 - Postman**

[image: Postman]

Comment: Have you tested in postman?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in postman.

Comment: check, Is it returning 200 OK in postman?

Comment: @KishoreJethava see my edit

Comment: Couldn't point any issue in this. Strange to see the error.

Comment: Take a look on [Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918814/use-jsonreader-setlenienttrue-to-accept-malformed-json-at-line-1-column-1-path) and [Retrofit2.0 gets MalformedJsonException while the json seems correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984898/retrofit2-0-gets-malformedjsonexception-while-the-json-seems-correct)

Comment: I tested it, it is in my question.

Comment: Can't find anything wrong with this. Only thing that comes to mind is that you're actually not getting what you expect due to some other error. Did you try adding logs to Retrofit to see what response to you actually get? From my experience postman adds some default headers that Retrofit doesn't and some servers can't cope with this and return some unexpected response.

Comment: @Alan, have you fixed this bug? In case it still does not work, you need to log `JSON` payload and use [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to validate it. In case it is not valid you need to preremove invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it took me a lot of time to figure it out.

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903479/3971619

TLDR: The BASE_URL variable used to create the Retrofit object should not have anything after the /

Replace:

```
val authApiService = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://test.com/api/test") //There is path after the /
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build().create(AuthService::class.java)
```

By

```
val authApiService = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://test.com/") //It should only be the base url without a path
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build().create(ServiceClass::class.java)
```